# Remove file path from a list of file names

Tags: r

I have a list of files and all the file names have the file paths as well.

```
   [1] c:/temp/dat/work/A0017517.T c:/temp/dat/work/A0017530.T
   [3] c:/temp/dat/work/A0017565.T c:/temp/dat/work/A0017588.T
   [5] c:/temp/dat/work/A0017620.T c:/temp/dat/work/A0017697.T
   [7] c:/temp/dat/work/A0018123.T c:/temp/dat/work/A0018124.T
```

I just want to get a list of file names without any file path. I tried basename() but I don't know how to use it on a list.
Thanks in advance for your help!

For some reason everything is messed up when I try to comment-
I have a csv file which looks like this-

```
"","size","isdir","mode","mtime"
"C/temp/A0017517.T",122099,FALSE,666,2015-10-08 13:39:26
"C/temp/A0017530.T",122706,FALSE,666,2015-10-08 13:39:26
"C/temp/A0017565.T",76613,FALSE,666,2015-10-01 20:37:24
"C/temp/A0017588.T",162651,FALSE,666,2015-10-08 13:39:28
```

All I want to do is to extract the first column which has filenames along with file paths and get a text file with just the file names (no file path).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sub('.*/', '', x)
#[1] "A0017517.T" "A0017530.T" "A0017565.T" "A0017588.T"
#[5] "A0017620.T" "A0017697.T" "A0018123.T" "A0018124.T"
```

The regex wildcard `".*"` will be greedy and gather as much of the string as it can taking in all of the forward slashes to the last one.

There's also:

```
basename(x)
#[1] "A0017517.T" "A0017530.T" "A0017565.T" "A0017588.T"
#[5] "A0017620.T" "A0017697.T" "A0018123.T" "A0018124.T"
```

**Update**

From your comments it appears that you have a data frame. The approach does not change. Just in case you have factors `basename` requires you to coerce the vector to `as.character`.

```
df
                         file size isdir
1 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017517.T   93  TRUE
2 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017530.T   60  TRUE
3 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017565.T   55 FALSE
4 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017588.T   52  TRUE
5 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017620.T   95  TRUE
6 c:/temp/dat/work/A0017697.T   49 FALSE
7 c:/temp/dat/work/A0018123.T   65  TRUE
8 c:/temp/dat/work/A0018124.T   56 FALSE

basename(as.character(df[,1]))
[1] "A0017517.T" "A0017530.T" "A0017565.T" "A0017588.T"
[5] "A0017620.T" "A0017697.T" "A0018123.T" "A0018124.T"

#or
sub('.*/', '', df[,1])
[1] "A0017517.T" "A0017530.T" "A0017565.T" "A0017588.T"
[5] "A0017620.T" "A0017697.T" "A0018123.T" "A0018124.T"
```

Comment: I was going to say, sub("c:/temp/dat/work/svrimp/","",x) but the use of regular expressions is better if the OP understands them.

Comment: @user1945827 you want something that's ready for any path name

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune-I tried but it gave me [1] "1:2777". I am new to R so its possible that I am making a mistake somewhere else but I am not sure where.

Comment: @PierreLafortune agreed.

Comment: Saying what output you're getting will not help as much as showing the actual code.

Comment: @asmi when you say you have a list ... what exactly do you have?  It has been assumed that you have a vector of characters.  Can you give more details?

Comment: If you do have a list and let's say it is called A, then the following will work, lapply(A, function(x) sub('.*/', '',x)) based on @PierreLafortune 's answer.  But we're still unsure what you've got.

Comment: Judging by the sample, it's not a list. But OP can give `class(mytext)` to be sure.

Comment: @PierreLafortune- I have a csv file with file names along with file path and other information -                                "","size","isdir","mode","mtime"
"C:\temp/A0017517.T",122099,FALSE,666,2015-10-08 13:39:26
"C:\tempA0017530.T",122706,FALSE,666,2015-10-08 13:39:26
 And I am just trying to extract the first column which has filenames along with file paths. I only want to have the file names in a text file (no file path).

Answer (score 1):

What about simply
`files <- list.files("c:/temp/dat/work/")`

Comment: You are assuming that the files are on the local hard drive