# Remove a sequence in a character in R

Tags: r, character

I have the following character in a data.frame:

```
b <- "http://datos.labcd.mx/dataset/5b18cc1e-d2f2-46b0-bf2c-e699ae2af713/resource/e265a46f-7a9f-4a30-ae0d-d5937fff17c1/download/201003.csv"
```

I just want to extract the number `201003`.

How should I do that?

Comment: Try `sub(".csv","",tail(strsplit(b,"/")[[1]],1))`

Comment: Or `sub(".*/(.*).csv", "\\1", b)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025246/remove-file-path-from-a-list-of-file-names

Comment: @PierreLafortune Yeah, I never really liked regex. Though I admit your code is shorter and therefore, I believe, generally preferable on SO.

Comment: Nobody likes regex, you just learn to live with it...

Comment: Or `sub("\\..*", "", basename(b))` for an easier route

Comment: Both works great, Cheers

Comment: @cory copyright that before someone else does

Answer (score 1):

```
b <- "http://datos.labcd.mx/dataset/5b18cc1e-d2f2-46b0-bf2c-e699ae2af713/resource/e265a46f-7a9f-4a30-ae0d-d5937fff17c1/download/201003.csv"
```

Try this on 'b':

```
file_name <- basename(b)
file_name
# [1] "201003.csv"
number <- strsplit(file_name, "\\.")[[1]]
number
# [1] "201003"  "csv"
number = as.numeric(number[1])
number
# [1] 201003
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very mucho to all of you. I solved my problem with your anwers